# CSS mousehover colors for li and a

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, mousehover

Hi i have a list menu as li --> a type in a site i want to make "a" 's text color white when "li" is mouse hover. The space in "a" content is smaller than the content of "li"  so im in a little conflict here. The following images can be helpful you to understand what i'm saying.

[image: a content]

[image: li content]

Answer (score 3):

Would the following not work?

```
li:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: li is changing to the color but the text is inside the "a" so i want to make sure the text to be changed while the "li" color also